# Sorting and matching

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nssortdescriptor

```
NSMutableArray *full_text_list = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [full_text_list addObject:@"for"];
    [full_text_list addObject:@"for your information"];
    [full_text_list addObject:@"you"];
    [full_text_list addObject:@"at"];

    NSMutableArray *short_text_list = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [short_text_list addObject:@"4"];
    [short_text_list addObject:@"fyi"];
    [short_text_list addObject:@"u"];
    [short_text_list addObject:@"@"];
```

**i dont want to sort the second array.** i want to get the appropriate element based on index.
I want to sort only the full_text_list array based on length, so i tried a below

```
NSSortDescriptor * descriptors = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"length" 
  ascending:NO] autorelease];

  NSArray * sortedArray = [full_text_list sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
  [NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptors]];
```

and the above code works fine.But i am not sure how to match short_text_list array with new sorted array

```
So when doing like [full_text_list objectatindex:0] and [short_text_list objectatindex:0] will not match

result would be "for your information" and "for" but the result should be "for your information" and "fyi"
```

Please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A second way to do this would be:

```
// Create your two arrays and then combine them into one dictionary:
NSDictionary *textDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:short_text_list 
                                                     forKeys:full_text_list];

// Create your sorted array like you did before:
NSSortDescriptor * descriptors = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"length" ascending:NO] autorelease];
NSArray * sortedArray = [full_text_list sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptors]];

// Then to access short_text, you would use:
NSString *object0ShortText = [textDict objectForKey:[sortedArray objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Comment: Using the exact same code that you used before.  You aren't actually sorting the dictionary here, just the original full_text_list and using the sortedArray that you created.  Then you look up the full_text_list value (that is in sortedArray) in the dictionary to find the short_text_list value that matches.

Comment: You are welcome!  Keep in mind that the other approach, while slightly more complicated, is actually easier to keep track of and uses less memory.  This one is the easier of the two though!

Answer (score 1):

How should it match? You have two arrays and are just sorting one and expect the second one automagically gets sorted too? This can not work. Why don't you just build a dictionary with the long information as key and the short  one as value or vs?

Comment: i dont want to sort the second array. i want to get the appropriate element based on index

Comment: And how  do you think fyi will move to the top of the second  list? It  surely will stay at index 1 (asuming that addObject add at the end). How can you expect that the second array is touched by anything done to the first array?

Comment: thanks for the reply. both the arrays are dynamic and comes from db.when sorting full_text_list array based on length, the order may gets changed.both arrays are like a key pair value.so if the full_text_list order gets changed means i cant match with short_text_list.

Comment: Can't be sorry. See the code of the other answer that will probably work. In your code there is no connection between the elements of full and short list.  If you do not change that nothing will work.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new class which contains both values and insert that into the array instead of creating the two separate array's in the first place:

```
@interface TextList : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *full_text;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *short_text;

- (TextList *)initWithFullText:(NSString *)full_text shortText:(NSString *)short_text;

@end
```

Create your .m file, and then when you want to use it, use something like:

```
NSMutableArray *full_text_list = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[full_text_list addObject:[TextList initWithFullText:@"for" shortText:@"4"]];
[full_text_list addObject:[TextList initWithFullText:@"for your information" shortText:@"fyi"]];
[full_text_list addObject:[TextList initWithFullText:@"you" shortText:@"u"]];
[full_text_list addObject:[TextList initWithFullText:@"at" shortText:@"@"]];
```

Then perform the sort:

```
NSSortDescriptor * descriptors = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"full_text.length" ascending:NO] autorelease];

NSArray * sortedArray = [full_text_list sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptors]];
```

Now you can do `[[sortedArray objectAtIndex:0] full_text];` and `[[sortedArray objectAtIndex:0] short_text];` or

```
TextList *txtList = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:0];
// txtList.full_text and txtList.short_text are both valid.
```